# Claims Based Authentication with OpenId Connect

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, openid-connect, aspnet-contrib, openiddict

I am using ASP.NET Core with OpenIddict, JWT, Resource Owner Grant and claims-based role. Authorization without enforcing any policy is working as expected.

I want to enforce authorisation policies on some controllers and action methods. All my users have role claims, so I did the following in the Startup:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", p => p.RequireClaim("Admin");
});
```

And I did the following on the action method:

```
[Authorize("Admin")]
public async Task<string> Index()
{
    return "Yes";
}
```

Without "Admin", I was able to access the resource, after adding "Admin" I can't.

I am assuming that because my generated JWT Token doesn't have the user claims.

- Should my JWT contain the user role claim for the token to work?
- How can I send the role claims using OpenIddict?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to request the `roles` scope for the roles to be copied in the access token (it may change in the future).

```
POST /connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&username=johndoe&password=A3ddj3w&scope=roles
```

Comment: I did this and it returned the roles to the token. But then I had to modify my policy to Require Roles rather than claims, which wasn't my intention, but it works now, thank you.